# ¿Por qué cuando hago hover en la imagen, la imagen se desborda pero el degradado se ve bien y no se desborda?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]El objetivo de la práctica era que aparecieran dos efectos al mismo  tiempo que se hace hover, los cuales son:

- Hacer grande la foto
- Añadir un gradiente con una opacidad ligera para que se va la imagen

El gradiente funciona super bien pero la imagen se desborda cuando se aplica la transformación a escala.

Por estar el problema en el hover, sólo se expande en el hover y si uno mantiene el cursor, regresa al tamaño al que debería, haciendo un salto en la imagen que se ve bastante feo.

Me pueden ayudar por favor a ver que pasa??

Muchas gracias :D

```css
.gal .box-img{
  overflow: hidden;

}

.box-img{
  overflow: hidden;
}


.box-img:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
}


.gal .box-img a{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gal .box-img a:after{

 
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(57, 85, 255, 0.7)), to(rgba(1, 102, 188, 0.1)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(57, 85, 255, 0.7), rgba(1, 102, 188, 0.1));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(57, 85, 255, 0.7), rgba(1, 102, 188, 0.1));
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 350px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;


}


.gal a:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;

}

.box-img{
  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.box-img img{
  max-width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;

}

  .gal img{
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="gal">
   <div class="box-img">    
    <a href="img/gallery/masonry/1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">
        <img src="img/gallery/masonry/1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="auto"> 
    </a>
   </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien cual es el problema, el código parece funcionar correctamente, ¿podrías indicar en que sentido la imagen se desborda?

Comment: de hecho ya vi que sí funciona bien si le quito transition, ahi sí se ve bien tanto el gradiente como la imagen (no se desborda) pero sin la transition da unos saltos feos la imagen al hacer el hover

Comment: parece estar funcionando todo bien en chrome, puedes mencionar en que navegador te está dando el problema?

Comment: estoy usando chrome :S de hecho quitando todas las transitions ya funciona bien pero al hacer hover se ve mal, osea da un salto la imagen

Comment: para probar el error que mencionas le di `border: 1px solid black` a cada objeto de tu ejemplo y te digo que la imagen jamas se desborda, puedes agregar una imagen o algo para que quede claro el error que mencionas?

Comment: listo!! subí la imagen donde se desborda, pero me parece extraño como quitando transitions ya funciona, el problema es que el movimiento no se ve suave

Comment: creo que puedes resolver tu problema moviendo la linea `transform: scale(1.2);` del div a la imagen directamente, ya que el `overflow: hidden;` esta asignado al div y cuando funciona la transformación afecta a todo el div de modo que el excedente no se oculta.

Comment: osea la línea de transform:scale(1.2) de .box-img:hover img a donde  .box-img img?

Comment: pude arreglar mi problema pero ahora dos imágenes presentan ese problema, el resto no, intentaré subir otra pregunta al respecto